# How to get a value of local variable outside the function in java script

Tags: javascript, function, object

New to Javascript - how to print value of "sam" outside the employee object

```html
<html>
      <head>
       <script>
         var employee = {
            empname: "David",
            department : "Finance",
            id : 002,
            details : function() {
                
                this.empname = "Sam";
               return this.empname + " with Department " + this.department;
            }
         };

         document.write(employee.empname);
         </script>
       </head>
    </html>
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You have to call the details function employee.details()

Answer (score 4):

You are updating the value of empname to **Sam** in details method , you need to call that method and then you use it .

```html
<html>
      <head>
       <script>
         var employee = {
            empname: "David",
            department : "Finance",
            id : 002,
            details : function() {
                
                this.empname = "Sam";
               return this.empname + " with Department " + this.department;
            }
         };
         employee.details()
         document.write(employee.empname);
         </script>
       </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: Great to hear it helped you . I hope you wont mind accepting the answer for better visibility.

Comment: You can upvote my question too. If you found it a good questions for learner(freshers)